# How to install Truffle 3.x, current release is Truffle 4.0

Tags: contract-development, truffle

Hello I have some code examples which seem to work on Truffle 3.x but breakup with Truffle 4.x

Is there a way I can specify in Powershell to install Truffle 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), you can:

1. Uninstall Truffle

   npm uninstall -g truffle
2. Reinstall a specific version of Truffle

   npm install -g truffle@3.4.6